# SQL Server Procedure for Access multiple Dynamic Database

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, dynamic

I'm creating procedure in SQL server. I'd like to work on multiple dynamic database. I understand that we could use `exec('Use ['+@db1+']')` for one dynamic database. But, What I want is using two dynamic database in the same server for join table. Like this:

```
declare @db1 varchar(max)
set @db1= (select name from sbr.dbo.snapshot_list where year(created_date) = @year1 and type='annual')
declare @db2 varchar(max)
set @db2= (select name from sbr.dbo.snapshot_list where year(created_date) = @year2 and type='annual')
set @exit= (select COUNT(DISTINCT y.id)
    FROM  @db1.dbo.common as y1
    JOIN @db2.dbo.common as y2 
            ON y2.id= y1.id
    where y1.status= '1' and y.status='4')
```

Is somebody know how to solve that?

**Also**
Maybe I should add this. I tried using exec() and assign it to variable (@exit), but It produce error near execute.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql= 'select COUNT(DISTINCT y.id)
FROM  '+@db1+'.dbo.common as y1
JOIN '+@db2+'.dbo.common as y2 
        ON y2.id= y1.id
where y1.status= 1 and y.status=4'
set @exit = exec(@sql)
```

Comment: That is a trivial dynamic sql. Go on with that sample `exec('use'+@db)` just build the query you need instead of `use db`. You have everything you need to solve this right in your question. 1) you know how to build `dynamic` query 2) you know all variables to build that query 3) you know how must the final query look like.

Comment: @IvanStarostin yes, but I still confused how I set the variable from the join. If I used `set @exit = execute('something')`, it shows incorrect syntax near execute.

Comment: `@exit` is supposed to be your dynamic-sql string. Dynamic sql is a string which contains sql code. Like here: `exec('use' + @db)`. All you need is to build your own string: `'select ...' + @db + '.dbo.common ...'`

Comment: @IvanStarostin : so, you mean something like this? `declare @result integer
set @exit= 'select COUNT(DISTINCT y.id)
    FROM  '+@db1+'.dbo.common as y1
    JOIN '+@db2+'.dbo.common as y2 
            ON y2.id= y1.id
    where y1.status= 1 and y.status=4'
set @result = execute(@exit)
set @result = exec(@exit)`

Comment: `set @exit = execute(@sql)` - here is a mistake. Take a look at other examples "how to return variable from dynamic sql". They should use `sp_executesql`

Comment: I've add it in the question.

Comment: Ok! I'll look about it!

Comment: @IvanStarostin, you can post your comment as answer. I'll accept it

Comment: too long to write... :)